# VBA: Checking optional parameters

Tags: excel, vba, optional-parameters

I have two subs and want to pass values from one to the other.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Call HandleInput(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C4"), 4, 2)
End Sub

Sub HandleInput(rng As Range, rowNumber As Long, colNumber As Long)
    Debug.Print rng.Cells(rowNumber, colNumber).Value
End Sub
```

However, sometimes I want to apply the same routine over the same range, but with a different `rownumber` and a different `colnumber`. I could just call the sub again with the new values and right now that seems to be by far the easiest option, but I still want know if there's a smart way to handle it with optional parameters in `HandleInput`:

```
Sub HandleInput(rng As Range, rowNumber As Long, colNumber As Long, Optional rowNumber2 As Long, _
Optional colNumber2 As Long, Optional rowNumber3 As Long, Optional colNumber3 As Long)
   ...
End Sub
```

This made me wonder:

Can I somehow tell VBA that, if `rowNumber2` is being provided, a value for `colNumber2` needs to be passed as well? I know I could try it with `IsMissing()` and switching the data type to `Variant`:

```
Sub HandleInput(rng As Range, rowNumber As Long, colNumber As Long, Optional rowNumber2 As Variant, 
     _ Optional colNumber2 As Variant, Optional rowNumber3 As Variant, Optional colNumber3 As Variant)
          If Not IsMissing(rowNumber2) Then
              If IsMissing(colNumber2) Then
                   MsgBox "Please enter a value for colNumber2."
                   End
              End If
          End If
End Sub
```

This requires lots of if-Statements, also in the other direction, (`If NOT IsMissing(colNumber2) Then`). And it only gets worse if more than two variables should be tied together. Any calculation that I try as a workaround gives me an error ("Type mismatch") when one value is missing, for example I tried:

```
If IsError(rowNumber2 * colNumber2) Then
   MsgBox "Error, please supply both rowNumber2 and colNumber2"
End If
```

Is there a native functionality for this? The only solution I came up with is supplying default values that I know won't occur "naturally":

```
Sub HandleInput(rng As Range, rowNumber As Long, colNumber As Long, Optional rowNumber2 As Long = -100, _
Optional colNumber2 As Long = -100, Optional rowNumber3 As Long = -100, Optional colNumber3 As Long = -100)

     If rowNumber2 = -100 Or colNumber2 = -100 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a value for both rowNumber2 and colNumber2."
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use an array as the arguments https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/passing-arrays.htm

Comment: Review the concepts in passing parameters either [`ByRef` or `ByVal`](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx). Then make it a habit to tag every single parameter with one of those keywords.

Comment: @Peter T Will do, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle the whoile thig with a [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) and range check the incomoing array

```
Sub HandleInput(rng As Range, ParamArray RCPairs() As Variant)

    If UBound(RCPairs) < 1 Then
        Err.Raise 513, "HandleInput", "Please enter at least one pair of RowNumber, ColNumber."
    ElseIf UBound(RCPairs) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 513, "HandleInput", "Please enter a value for both RowNumber and ColNumber."
    End If

    ' ...

End Sub
```

Called like this

```
Sub Demo()
    HandleInput SomeRange, r1, c1, r2, c2 ' Works

    HandleInput SomeRange ' Error "Please enter at least one pair of RowNumber, ColNumber."

    HandleInput SomeRange, r1, c1, r2, c2, x ' Error: "Please enter a value for both RowNumber and ColNumber."

End Sub
```

Note: I cahnged your `MsgBox`, `End` to raising an error, so your calling code can decide what to do about the error.  BTW using `End` is unwise, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008904)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Answer (score 5):

Magic defaults are a bad idea.

You need a concept of *"something that represents two values that need to always go together"* - that sounds very much like needing some kind of [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.8) object that encapsulates two values; I'd go with the nuclear strongly-typed option, and add two new class modules - first some general-purpose `ITuple` interface:

```
'@Interface
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Item1() As Variant
End Property

Public Property Get Item2() As Variant
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
End Function
```

And then a `RangeLocation` class that implements it:

```
'@PredeclaredId 'see https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations
Option Explicit
Implements ITuple

Private Type TInternal
    RowIndex As Long
    ColumnIndex As Long
End Type

Private this As TInternal

Public Function Create(ByVal atRow As Long, ByVal atColumn As Long) As ITuple
    Dim result As RangeLocation
    Set result = New RangeLocation
    result.RowIndex = atRow
    result.ColumnIndex = atColumn
    Set Create = result
End Function

Public Property Get RowIndex() As Long
    RowIndex = this.RowIndex
End Property

Public Property Let RowIndex(ByVal value As Long)
    If value <= 0 Then Err.Raise 5
    this.RowIndex = value
End Property

Public Property Get ColumnIndex() As Long
    ColumnIndex = this.ColumnIndex
End Property

Public Property Let ColumnIndex(ByVal value As Long)
    If value <= 0 Then Err.Raise 5
    this.ColumnIndex = value
End Property

Private Property Get ITuple_Item1() As Variant
    ITuple_Item1 = this.RowIndex
End Property

Private Property Get ITuple_Item2() As Variant
    ITuple_Item2 = this.ColumnIndex
End Property

Private Function ITuple_ToString() As String
    ITuple_ToString = "R" & this.RowIndex & "C" & this.ColumnIndex
End Function
```

Note how it's impossible to have an instance of that object that encapsulates a negative row or column index. And now we can do this:

```
Dim a As ITuple
Set a = RangeLocation.Create(1, 1)
```

Which means we can also do this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal source As Range, ParamArray values() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)

        Dim location As ITuple
        Set location = values(i)

        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print source.Cells(location.Item1, location.Item2).Value
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Location " & location.ToString & " is outside the specified source range."
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next
End Sub
```

...and it's now somebody else's job to make sure they're providing valid values - more precisely, it's the calling code's job:

```
Dim source As Range
Set source = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C4")

DoSomething source, _
    RangeLocation.Create(4, 2), _
    RangeLocation.Create(1, 1), _
    RangeLocation.Create(2, 2)
    '...
```

If the caller tries to do `RangeLocation.Create(0, -12)`, there will be a runtime error (because the `Property Let` members of the `RangeLocation` class don't allow negative values) and `DoSomething` will not even be invoked.